# Proving $9a^2+9b^2+9c^2 = (p_1a + q_1b + r_1c)^2 + (p_2a + q_2b + r_2c)^2 + (p_3a + q_3b + r_3c)^2$ where $p_j, q_j, r_j$ are all nonzero integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n = a^2+b^2+c^2$
> for
> some natural numbers $a, b, c$. Prove that
> $$9n = (p_1a + q_1b + r_1c)^2
>  + (p_2a + q_2b + r_2c)^
> 2 + (p_3a + q_3b + r_3c)^
> 2$$
> where $p_j,  q_j, r_j$ are all nonzero integers.

The question asks me to prove $9a^2+9b^2+9c^2 = (p_1a + q_1b + r_1c)^2
 + (p_2a + q_2b + r_2c)^
2 + (p_3a + q_3b + r_3c)^
2$.

If for some $(p_j,  q_j, r_j)\in \Bbb{Z}$,  $$3a=p_1a + q_1b + r_1c$$$$3b=p_2a + q_2b + r_2c$$
$$3c=p_3a + q_3b + r_3c$$
Then the given equation will automatically be proven correct.

The first equation gives $(3a-p_1)a = q_1b + r_1c$. This diophantine equation solution iff $(b, c) | (3a-p_1)a$. This condition will be easily satisfied for many $p_1 , q_1, r_1$. Same goes for second and third equations.

This is my proof.

Is this proof ? The question seems too easy to be a Olympiad question. I think it has some mistakes. Can anyone please verify it ?

This question is taken from INMO 2007.

Comment: This is only one part of the question, right? I would believe this part is supposed to be as a hint to solve the next part: Proving that if we also know that $3$ does not divide at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$, then $9n = x^2+y^2+z^2$ for some natural numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ where none of the three numbers are divisible by $3$. There are many possible solutions for $p_j$, $q_j$, $r_j$, but maybe not all will help you solve the second part of the question.

Comment: FYI, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%249n%3D(p_1a%2Bq_1b%2Br_1c)%5E2%2B(p_2a%2Bq_2b%2Br_2c)%5E%202%2B(p_3a%2Bq_3b%2Br_3c)%5E%202%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%3Da%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1) listed the AoPS thread [Prove that 9n can be expressed in the required form...](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h309550p1671319). Note this thread includes the second part mentioned in VTand's comment above, as well as giving a solution for that part.

Comment: You have not proven anything. The mistake you you made is: Even though the condition will be easily satisfies for many $p_i, q_i, r_i$, how do you know that there is a value that satisfies all 3 equations at the same time?